# Volley & Android internet permission not working

Tags: android, android-volley, android-permissions

I'm trying to use volley.

This is my android manifest: (i've added access_network_state because of suggestion but not really needed i think)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.informaticalab.volleyexample" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the logcat:

```
12-20 18:02:02.804  32718-32741/com.informaticalab.volleyexample E/Volley﹕ [10218] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
12-20 18:02:56.885      720-743/com.informaticalab.volleyexample E/Volley﹕ [10263] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
12-20 18:04:31.940    1819-1841/com.informaticalab.volleyexample E/Volley﹕ [10403] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
            at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:109)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

I' m not sure what i'm doing wrong. Even if the logcat says that there is a permission problem, i would like to attach my main activity too:

```
package com.informaticalab.volleyexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        String url = "";

        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                    {
                        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: Oooops!");
                    }
                });

// Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private static class MySingleton
    {
        private static MySingleton mInstance;
        private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private static Context mCtx;

        private MySingleton(Context context)
        {
            mCtx = context;
            mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                                           new ImageLoader.ImageCache()
                                           {
                                               private final android.support.v4.util
                                                       .LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                                                       cache = new android.support.v4.util
                                                       .LruCache<String, Bitmap>(
                                                       20);

                                               @Override
                                               public Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
                                               {
                                                   return cache.get(url);
                                               }

                                               @Override
                                               public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap)
                                               {
                                                   cache.put(url, bitmap);
                                               }
                                           });
        }

        public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context)
        {
            if (mInstance == null)
            {
                mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
            }
            return mInstance;
        }

        public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
        {
            if (mRequestQueue == null)
            {
                // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
                // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return mRequestQueue;
        }

        public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req)
        {
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }

        public ImageLoader getImageLoader()
        {
            return mImageLoader;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: *removed unnecessary statement.*

---

You are right, the:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

is not necessary. You only need the INTERNET permission.

But all of this, has not really anything to do with the problem of your missing permissions. I'm doing it like you and it works like a charm. Simply test my thoughts above and report back.

Comment: android:name=".MainActivity" will work if the manifests package is com.informaticalab.volleyexample

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2-cent, I had similar issue. After I update my AndroidManifest.xml to contain android.permission.INTERNET permission, I still got  java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?) in my logcat.

I simply disconnected and reconnected my Android phone and it works. Maybe you can try to do that.

You can also check if there is an Internet permission by going to Setting > App > "YourApp", scrolling all the way to the bottom under PERMISSIONS section and see if there is "Full Network Access" text or not.

Hope this help,
Cheers

Comment: OMG thanks a lot it worked for me in latest android studio @ Pixel XL Simulator. I thought it was something complex and would takes whole day to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Add   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the AndroidMenifest.xml file as attribute of  < application > tag . Its important from android 9